# Simple Mercurial extension fails to import

Tags: python, mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-extension

I'm trying to follow the sample code for [writing Mercurial extensions](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WritingExtensions). This is a minimal sample, copied verbatim from the sample code:

```
from mercurial import cmdutil
from mercurial.i18n import _

cmdtable = {}
command = cmdutil.command(cmdtable)
```

I save this to a file  and install the extension in my `.hgrc` file like so:

```
[extensions]
myext=C:\foo\myext.py
```

Any subsequently issued command, like e.g. `hg init` now results in the following error message:

> *** failed to import extension myext from C:\foo\myext.py: 'module' object has no attribute 'command'

Could this possibly be caused by a faulty environment, e.g. missing environment variables?

I'm using Mercurial 4.7 on Windows 10, installed by the TortoiseHg installer (tortoisehg-4.7.0-x64). Mercurial uses Python 2.7.13, also installed by the TortoiseHg installer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like the documentation needs to be updated. `command` was [moved from `cmdutil` to `registrar` in January, 2016](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg-committed/rev/46ba2cdda476) though an alias was left in place at that time. This was [marked as deprecated in November, 2017](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg-committed/rev/b22a0d9e0a83) and [removed entirely in May, 2018](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg-committed/rev/fb0de0bcd297).

The [Mercurial 4.7 release in August, 2018](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew#Mercurial_4.6.1_.282018-06-06.29) [included the change that removed `cmdutil.command`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Release4.7):

> cmdutil: drop deprecated precursor of registrar.command (API)

This works for me:

```
from mercurial import registrar
from mercurial.i18n import _

cmdtable = {}
command = registrar.command(cmdtable)
```